# How to enable Visualization view by default in Neo4j WebAdmin data browser panel

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Due to a particular development requirement, I have to display the data as displayed in dataBrowser of neo4j web panel in an external Iframe/Div. 
The thing is I want it to appear in Visualization mode instead of tabular view which is enabled by default. The views are switched by clicking on the button *Switch view mode.*

Are there any configuration settings that I can use for displaying the Visualization mode / graphical view first, If not what might be other ways to achieve this.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The visualizer seems to be a bit undeveloped/bugged. The only way I found to use it, was to run a query, select a node/relationship from the result(tabular view) and then switch tu Visualization mode. Then the selected node and all direct relationships should be visualized. By clicking on nodes, the visualizer will load any relationships connected to those.
Unfortunatly there is no way to display the whole graph(besides clicking through all nodes...)

Comment: Actually, I have my data available in Visualization mode, All that I want is when browsing through data browser it should display the visualization mode by default instead of tabular mode. Purpose being I want to plug the visualization thingy in a div of an app.